# HttpClient POST gets html page about 2.5x slower than browser

Tags: java, http, httpclient

When I hit Search on [London journey planner](http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk/user/XSLT_TRIP_REQUEST2?language=en) (e.g from Holborn to Savoy Pier), I get result in about 4 secs. When I do that with HttpClient using POST method, this line takes about 10 secs:

```
InputStream is = httpClient.execute(httpPost).getEntity().getContent();
```

Any ideas what can be the problem? I'm sending the same parameters as browser and I have also set User-Agent to Chrome.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and quicker just to walk from Holborn to Savoy Pier? :)

Comment: LOL!!! :D I'm trying to do London journey planner for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to say, what is your problem, without seeing the code that performs the test and the measurement.

One suggestion, for **troubleshooting with HttpClient**: [use logging](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html).

And, to remove human errors from this comparison, it would be advisable to **use some command-line tool** (e.g. wget) instead of the browser to perform the comparative POST.